# Issues on installing ionic3 in windows7

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am installing ionic on windows 7 & the process that i am following is:

Updated node and NPM to the higher version available(10.16) &  node(6.1)

```
npm install -g ionic@version
npm install -g cordova@version
```

command run successfully with few deprecation warnings.

result that i am getting on "ionic serve" command is ionic is not recognized.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after installing npm , ionic , cordova you should restart your system to make effects on system variables 
just restart your system